# Javascript add +1

Tags: javascript, syntax

Can someone please help me with the simplest question ever.

```
var rate = (month * "0.004545");
```

I simply need to get rate to be the above value + 1.
I just need (X * Y) + 1

All values are numbers.
Would truly appreciate this, I have already spent 1 hour.

Comment: `var rate = (month * 0.004545) + 1`. Note that you don't need quotes.

Comment: `"0.004545"` is a value, but *not* a number.

Comment: `var rate = (month * "0.004545") + 1;` works just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/7qubck5w/. If your browser crashes, then the problem is somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

Just add (`+`) and remove the `"`s:

```
var rate = (month * 0.004545) + 1;
```

See [Arithmetic operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Addition_(.2B)) on MDN.

Also ensure that `month` is defined without `"`s.

---

**EDIT:** As it appears that you aren't being able to get this to work, here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jsve/v8k6o19d/) that demonstrates the code working for me.

Comment: Tried that, my browser simply crashes.

Comment: I even tried rate1 = x * Y and rate2 = rate1 + 1
or even ++rate1

nothing works...

Comment: FWIW whether the value is a string or a number doesn't make a difference in that case.

Answer (score 0):

```
var prerate = parseFloat(month) * 0.004545;
var rate = ++prerate;
```

Comment: Care to explain your solution? Why are you using `parseFloat`? Why are you introducing a new variable?